Previously working Excel Named Range gives a "Reference isn't valid" and returns error 1004 in a simple macro
I have a couple of files where previously good named ranges stopped working.  Running Office 365 for business, 64 bit, Win 11.
The named ranges appear in name manager with the correct cell reference and value.  However, "Go To" returns a "Reference isn't valid" and a simple macro to display the named range value returns a 1004 error.
Illustration of Name Manager, Go To and Code error
Sub Test_Range()
   MsgBox(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Input_QB").Value)
End Sub

The problem started after 15 Jul.  Another user noted a similar problem on microsoft.com and thought it was a bug with a version release (version 2406 build 16.0.17726.20078).  A moderator redirected the user to a MS feedback site (stopped the troubleshooting cold).   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/i-have-found-a-run-time-bug-error-1004-in/ab6f100a-8c89-4489-9c43-b08a5416f5c9
Things I have tried with no success:

Deleting the named range and using the same name to setup a new named range resulted in the same errors
Saving, closing, and reopening resulted in the same errors
"Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Input_QB").Value" resulted in the same error
"Range("Input_QB").Value" resulted in the same error
Rebuilding the Sheet and all the named ranges resulted in the same error

Strange Result:

Renaming the named range as a different name works ("Input_QBr"), however, restoring the old name ("Input_QB") results in the same 1004 error.

Feedback to Microsoft:  Reported as a problem via Help inside of Excel.

Check the scope of the named range. It should be set to "Workbook" if it's unique to the Workbook or the worksheet name if it's specific to a worksheet.

The scope is "Workbook" but I need to research the point you made.

I rebuilt the Named Range with the scope as the Worksheet "Dashboard" worksheet.  It still gave the same 1004 error.

What is the value in the referenced range? Is it a string?

Yes, it is a string "Test Named Range"

Please provide name's reference.

Refers to:  =Dashboard!$E$13

You can try un-Zipping the Excel file and editing its XML directly.  It's a rather drastic measure to take but one of the times I had this same issue, it did resolve it.  This involves changing the extension of your Excel file to .ZIP and then opening the ZIP file, searching for your named range in the XML files and deleting the code that creates the named range.  Then save your change and reset the file extension to .xlsm.  Just keep in mind that if you make a mistake in deleting the code, you can corrupt your file, so make sure you have a backup.

The most efficient way (workaround) to handle this is to rename all the named ranges in the Workbook and then update the references in the vba code.

Frank Ball's xml answer points to an issue inside Excel (the xml changes are beyond my abilities)
rotabor's answer is another workaround to Microsoft's issue (lots of work to employ workaround).  MsgBox Names("Input_QB").Value

If MS provides a response to my feedback, I will update this.

No solution - just first step for checking
Why not first get all the names which belongs to worksheets and check if it exists
Option Explicit

Sub ShowNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim na As Name
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print "Worksheet: "; ws.Name
        For Each na In ws.Names
            Debug.Print na.Name
        Next na
    Next ws
End Sub


Ran the code and it did not return any of the named ranges on the Dashboard.  Searching for a way to replace "ws.Name" with ranges.

I ran this code and it displayed the Named Ranges as expected.  https://www.thesmallman.com/blog/2016/9/16/list-all-named-ranges-with-vba

Even with the Named Ranges displaying, the simple macro returns 1004 error.

what happens with:
MsgBox(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Input_QB").refersto)

Hi Red Hare.  Same error 1004

I only realize now, that you use the name for range address.
It is much better to use the referstorange :
MsgBox(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").names("foo").RefersToRange.Value
replace foo with your name

Thanks, Red Hare...unfortunately, that did not work either.  I even rebuilt the entire sheet and all the Named Ranges.  Something is wrong beneath the surface.

Modified the macro to display names in all scopes:
Option Explicit

Sub ShowNames()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim na As Name
  Debug.Print "Workbook's names:"
  For Each na In ThisWorkbook.Names
    Debug.Print na.Name
  Next
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print "Worksheet '"; ws.Name; "' names:"
    For Each na In ws.Names
      Debug.Print na.Name
    Next
  Next
End Sub

Also try to perform simple tests in the Immediate (Debug) window:
?Names("Input_QB").Name
?Sheets("Dashboard").Names("Input_QB").Name

Hope it can help to get the scope.
Alternatively, to call up workbook-scoped names:
   MsgBox Range("Input_QB").Value

The same can be applied for worksheet-scoped names if the active sheet is the sheet for which the name is defined, otherwise
   MsgBox Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Input_E13").Value


Thank you!!! First one worked and the second returned the same error message.  I am going to try Names in the code.

rotabor provided a workaround for the issue.  MsgBox (Names("Input_QB").Name)  Still, why did this stop working across a bunch of files after 15 Jul?

I appreciate the edits rotobor.  Neither Range nor Sheets worked.  This is an out of the ordinary issue that changed with one of the Office 365 releases.
